# Is it possible to pass network credentials to a web service from Silverlight UI?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

This problem is specifically in silverlight 3.0:

This the network credential object I created:

```
System.Net.NetworkCredential credential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mohammed.haroon", "abcdefg123");
```

And my web service is Service1

```
Service1 WebService = new Service1();

WebService.ClientCredentials = credential;

WebService.ExecuteSomeMethodAsync("xyz", "abc");
            WebService.ExecuteSomeMethodAsyncCompleted += WebService_ExecuteSomeMethodAsyncCompleted;
```

I am unable to sent credential to Webservice which is in windows authenticated, as it not possible to assign network credential to webservice ClientCredentials specifically in Silverlight 3.0

Is there any work-around to do that?

Comment: It would help if you indicated whether the web service is something you control and whether its intended to serve other types of clients

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:-

```
Service1 WebService = new Service1();

WebService.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "mohammed.haroon";

WebService.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "abcdefg123";

WebService.ExecuteSomeMethodAsync("xyz", "abc");
            WebService.ExecuteSomeMethodAsyncCompleted += WebService_ExecuteSomeMethodAsyncCompleted;
```

The `ClientCredentials` property is read only but it returns an instance of `ClientCredentials`  which only has a single  (unlike its full .NET 3.5 counter-part) readonly property `UserName` of type `UserNamePasswordClientCredential`.  This in turn is has read/write properties of `UserName` and `Password`.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that the .Net RIA services are a good framework for this sort of thing (i.e. authenticating from a silverlight control to a WCF webservice). You can find out more about this at [silverlight.net](http://silverlight.net/learn/), and the usual culprits such as [Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/) and [Tim Heuer](http://timheuer.com/blog/) have a lot of hands on examples on their blogs.

Comment: This assumes of course that the OP can modify the Web Service.